# Update of app shown in iPhone but not in iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-appstore, software-update

I have a first version of my app in the App Store. Recently I released the next version with some bug fixes. After Apple approved the updated version, the update showed in the App Store app for my iPhone but *not* for my iPad.

Is this my problem or Apple's?

Additional Information:

1. I have a single binary file for both the iPhone and iPad.
2. I had the first version of the app in both of my devices before I found this bug.

Comment: Did you change the minimum iOS requirement with the newer version?

Comment: Yes...my app requires 4.3 only. My iPad is 6.0.

Comment: Questions about software development are off-topic here. See [our FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more info.

Comment: iTunes Connect & friends are on-topic and the problem may be more related to Apple's deployment processes than to coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've noticed with universal apps, and also with iPhone only apps between my devices is that sometimes an update might come one day to one device and the next day to another and at the third day the last one gets it. Might be that Apple does this so their servers wont be overloaded when everybody updates the same app at the same time.

You should also check that you've released the update to all platforms, not only iPhones.

Comment: Thank you.I got update one day after. I hope this is a problem in apple side.